# I... Can't believe you grandfather!

Tags: knowledge, lateral-thinking

> Grandson, when I was born, there were no less than 2,005 times... Hum. One billion people, I think. Thank you calculator! In the world.
>
> — How come my old grandfather makes such en error?

<sub>**Note 1:** people who instantly gets the `knowledge` tag will benefit from it **a lot**. You are several in this website to have it **for sure**. I think with more research from those who don't have it, you still can figure out the puzzle and that'd be even more impressive!</sub>

<sub>**Note 2:** I believe it is possible that other answers apart from the one I thought exist. So I will only select the answer that matches mine, but feel free to post your tries as they'd could get +1 and a chance to be mine. That's why I added the `lateral-thinking` tag.</sub>

Comment: Is the comma in "2,005" used as a decimal separator or a digit group separator?

Comment: @Wolff - The OP is a "French Operations Research PhD student" so it is most likely a decimal separator, but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on

> The fact that the comma , is sometimes used as a decimal separator, then 2,005 billion = 2,005,000,000 people. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_population_milestones) the US Census Bureau estimates the world population hit 2 billion around 1927, and so it likely hit 2,005 billion a few years later (1930s-ish?). This would make your grandpa between 80-90 years old, which is reasonable!

Comment: The fact that we use comma as a decimal separator in my country threw me off. I couldn't see the "error". 

Answer (score 3):

A quite unlikely answer:

> His grandpa was born in Guatemala in 1807

Because:

> If we assume that by 'no more than a billion' he  meant about a billion, we know that it is about 1802-1820. If he knew that his country was one 2005th of the world, the we know that his country contained about 500,000 people. The most fitting >!one seems to be Guatemala but it could have easily been any of the following: 
>  
> Oman, Parma, Holstein, Timor, Austrian Silesia, Dalmatia, Duchy of Carinthia, Duchy of
> Carniola, Cuba, Nassau, Duchy of Mecklenburg-Schwerin, Canada, British Carribean

There is the problem that:

> Grandpa would be between 200 and 220

However:

> The question never says when Grandpa is saying this and it could be any time between then and now